# Can't test Java installation as normal user

Tags: java, firefox

I have installed java and firefox.

```
root@localhost:/home/debian# java -version
java version "1.8.0_45"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_45-b14)
Java HotSpot(TM) Server VM (build 25.45-b02, mixed mode)
```

And link libnpjp2.so  into firefox plugins directory.

```
ln  -s  /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/jre/lib/i386/libnpjp2.so    /usr/lib/mozilla/plugins/libnpjp2.so
```

Strange things happened in my pc that in my console:

1.when to input  `firefox http://java.com/en/download/testjava.jsp` with root ,

```
A newer version of Java is available
Please click the download button to get the recommended Java for your computer.
Your Java version: Version 8 Update 45
```

2.when to input  `firefox http://java.com/en/download/testjava.jsp` with normal user ,

```
Verify Java Version
We are unable to verify if Java is currently installed and enabled in your browser.
```

3.There is no java plugin displayed when to input `about:plugins` in my firefox.

[image]
How to  set java plugin properly in my firefox ?

Comment: is there also a `/usr/lib64/mozilla/plugins/` directory?

Answer (score 0):

Your user's profile isn't in `/usr/lib/mozilla/` but in `/home/user/.mozilla/`; therefore, you have to link the java plugin to there

```
ln -s /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/jre/lib/i386/libnpjp2.so /home/user/.mozilla/plugins/
```

Take a look at [this mozilla support thread](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/questions/980352#answer-513984) for some possible hints/alternative options.

As an alternative, install the `icedtea` plugin instead of the oracle browser plugin.

Also, check to make sure your java installation and your firefox package have the same architecture; i.e. 32-bit vs. 64-bit. Therefore, you might need to create the link in the `/usr/lib64/mozilla/plugins/` directory, if it exists.

Finally, try deleting the `pluginreg.dat` file in your profile directory:

```
rm -rf ~/.mozilla/firefox/some_weird_name.default/pluginreg.dat
```

This file will be recreated the next time you start firefox.

Comment: It is no use  ln -s /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/jre/lib/i386/libnpjp2.so  /home/debian/.mozilla/plugins/libnpjp2.so

Comment: then just stick with the `icedtea` plugin; not sure why you would absolutely NEED the oracle java plugin instead.